# Applying numerical integration twice (trapezoidal rule)

Tags: integration, matlab

This is basically a programming exercise in `matlab` but I do not understand the math behind it.

Say, that I have an `trapezoidArea` function defined like this:

```
function area=trapezoidArea(x1,x2,y1,y2)
    area=(x2-x1).*(y1+y2)/2; 
end
```

and my time and acceleration are as follows:

```
t=0:0.1:40;
a(1,1:201)=2;
a(1,201:301)=0;
a(1,301:401)=-4;
```

If I want to calculate velocity, I can integrate acceleration time series numerically:

```
t1=t(1:end-1);
t2=t(2:end);
a1=a(1,1:end-1);
a2=a(1,2:end);
v=transpose(trapezoidArea(t1,t2,a1,a2));
```

If I want to find displacement, then I have to apply `trapezoidArea` function again to velocity time series but the dimensions of velocity is smaller than the dimension of the time vector. So my question is how can I find displacement vector by numerically integrating acceleration twice? and why the method you describe works?

I was told to apply `cumsum` function to `v` and then remove the last element of `t` and then apply `trapezoidArea` to `v` and `t` but to be honest, I am not sure why this method works. When I use this method `sum(s)=1.004e3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `v=trapezoidArea(t1,t2,a1,a2)` function returns a vector of the velocity change over intervals `[t1(1),t2(1)], ... [t1(end),t2(end)]`. The actual velocity at times `t2(i)` is `v0+v(1)+...+v(i)`, where `v0` is the initial velocity.

You now have a vector of velocities at times `t2`, which you can extend to velocities at times `t` by prepending `v0` to `v`.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is how can I find displacement vector by numerically integrating acceleration twice? and why the method you describe works?

Because:
$$a=\frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}t}=\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\left(\frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t}\right)=\frac{{\rm d^2}x}{{\rm d}t^2}$$
So:
$$v-v_0=\int {\rm d}v=\int a{\rm d}t$$
And:
$$x-x_0=\int {\rm d}x=\int v{\rm d}t=\int\int a{\rm d}t{\rm d}t$$

Comment: I know that. When you use trapezoidal rule, you are applying it to t and a. If you have n values of a or t, then you have n-1 trapezoidal areas. Right? so if you want to integrate numerically again, you have n-1 values of v and n values of t. How would you find displacement when you have n-1 values of v and n values of t?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of thinking about this, I think I have got the answer. This answer is motivated by @Conrad Turner's answer. Let's call the velocity vector that is obtained by numerically integrating acceleration vector, be V and let's call the actual acceleration vector be v. It is clear that  $v(2)=V(1)$, $v(3)=V(1)+V(2)$ and in general $v(i)=V(1)+V(2)+\cdots+V(i-1)$. Therefore, the need for `cumsum`.